# Image registration problem : Very bad image registration result

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, image-registration

I am trying to perform image registration and my registration output is completely bad .

Following is my code , the images that i posses are models of wounds acquired at different camera angle, links for the acquired images and output image is provided below for your review

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

im1 = cv2.imread('/home/Documents/image_registration/1.jpg')          # Image that needs to be registered.
im2 = cv2.imread('/home/Documents/image_registration/3.jpg') # trainImage

img1 = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img2 = cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Initiate ORB detector
orb = cv2.ORB_create(5000)  #Registration works with at least 50 points

# find the keypoints and descriptors with orb
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1, None)  #kp1 --> list of keypoints
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

#Brute-Force matcher takes the descriptor of one feature in first set and is 
 # create Matcher object

matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv2.DESCRIPTOR_MATCHER_BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING)

# Match descriptors.
matches = matcher.match(des1, des2, None)  #Creates a list of all matches, just like keypoints

# Sort them in the order of their distance.
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

#Like we used cv2.drawKeypoints() to draw keypoints, 
#cv2.drawMatches() helps us to draw the matches. 
 
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(im1,kp1, im2, kp2, matches[:500], None)

#cv2.imshow("Matches image", img3)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

#Now let us use these key points to register two images. 
#Can be used for distortion correction or alignment
 
#Second set to #trainIdx. 

points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)  #Prints empty array of size equal to (matches, 2)
points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)

for i, match in enumerate(matches):
   points1[i, :] = kp1[match.queryIdx].pt    #gives index of the descriptor in the list of query descriptors
   points2[i, :] = kp2[match.trainIdx].pt    #gives index of the descriptor in the list of train descriptors

 
  
h, mask = cv2.findHomography(points1, points2, cv2.RANSAC)
 
  # Use homography
height, width, channels = im2.shape
im1Reg = cv2.warpPerspective(im1, h, (width, height))  #Applies a perspective transformation to an image.
   
print("Estimated homography : \n",  h)

#cv2.imshow("Registered image", im1Reg)
#cv2.waitKey()

cv2.imwrite ( '/home/Documents/image_registration/output.jpg' , im1Reg)
```

image 1
[image]

image 3

[image]

Output registration
[image]

Kindly suggest me the problem with  my approach

Comment: draw the matches. there's a function for that. and don't use ORB. use akaze or sift.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz , sift is not working any more with openCV new version , could you please provide me some example how to approach this problem

Comment: of course it works. why would you say otherwise? if you need an example, use `samples/python/find_obj.py` to be found in OpenCV source

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz sift is deprecated : sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
[ WARN:0@6.010] global /io/opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d/misc/python/shadow_sift.hpp (13) SIFT_create DEPRECATED: cv.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create() is deprecated due SIFT tranfer to the main repository. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16736

Comment: well yes, it was moved from contrib to main repository several years ago. it's no longer in `xfeatures2d`. the message says as much, even if it's not very clear about what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

in python tuples are **immutable** and sort function (in python list) is sorting **in place** and that's why it doesn't exist on tuples.
to sort the tuples you should use the sorted function which returns a new list

in your case -

```
sorted(matches, key = lambda x: x.distance)
```

Comment: I unable to register the images using the procedure, i am editing my answer, please check my question

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question, could you please check it and let me know how i possibly could resolve registration issue